# regular expressions with flags in either Textpad or Gedit

Tags: python, regex, flags, gedit, textpad

I would love to replace some paragraphs based upon a regular expression (python style) that needs flags `gms` to work properly.

To keep things simple, I would like to exclusively work with text editors (and dive in into the coding later on.

Is there a way to enable flags for regular expressions in either GEdit or TextPad for Windows?

Cheers, 
Andrew

Comment: what you mean with "flags"? Is it CTRL+F + regex?

Comment: flags are used to enable various features and syntax variations. see: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html and then "Compiling Regular Expressions"

Comment: Ah, ok, you mean RE.I, RE.M etc. However, by default gedit does not support regex search.

Comment: I see, thx. What about TextPad. It does support RegularExpressions in general. But do you know whether flags are possible there?

Comment: hmm... I'm do not know about TextPad but I hope it help you: [regexplanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/python/index.html) or [pythex](http://pythex.org/)